# Model attributes of existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a existing Database and I dont need to generate any models but I would
like to have also the columns of the tables inside the activerecord model.

I don't like to check everytime the columns of my table. I just need some kind of a reference to the column. And it looks pretty wrong to me not having them in the model.

Right now my models looks like this:

```
 class City < ActiveRecord::Base
      self.table_name = "city"
 end
```

Btw I am using rails 4.

Comment: as @maximus stated use `annotate`. I place this gem in every project just for this reason.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be the right way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like this gem https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models, where it annotate the structure of model from database table like below,

```
# == Schema Info
#
# Table name: line_items
#
#  id                  :integer(11)    not null, primary key
#  quantity            :integer(11)    not null
#  product_id          :integer(11)    not null
#  unit_price          :float

#  order_id            :integer(11)

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what i was looking for. If i understand you right, there is no technical need to notate the columns in my models?

Comment: Right, technically rails will not complain if you do not annotate the columns :P

Comment: Well i know it doesnt complain. I am was justing asking myself if i will need them later like in ASP.NET MVC where you can do a lot of thing with the columns directly in the EF model. Things like validation etc.

Comment: Well, it depends upon your feature needs. Database may contains more columns than actual need or vice versa. In such cases you may need to annotate.